# U2F devices: backdoors possible?

Tags: backdoor, u2f

Following the [recent post at ZDNet](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-launches-titan-security-keys-but-recommends-keys-from-chinese-firm-with-military-links-in/) on Google Titan devices designed and manufactured by a Chinese vendor and potentially prone to built-in backdoors: is it even theoretically possible to inject a backdoor on a U2F device, given the protocols and standards used?

If so, how could such backdoors actually work?

Answer (score 2):

A backdoor is actually quite simple: keep track of the secret key used on the device. Either by generating them randomly and storing them after writing to each device, or by generating them all from a known seed. All of the security of a U2F device is dependent on the device key staying secret.